# How to put comments while kicking a workflow off in touch ui AEM 6.1?

Tags: aem

When a user starts a workflow in touch UI using "Start Workflow" in `timeline`, there is an option of putting "`comments`". However, if the user puts the comment, it doesn't show up in the timeline or anywhere. Is it a bug? What is the expected behavior of "`comments`" section in `timeline`?

[image]

How can we put a comment while starting a workflow?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow comments are for passing data between workflow steps. A typical example would be to send an additional note from a workflow approve or reject step. Timeline does not display the comments OOTB as that will be too much of a generalisation for so little screen real state.

Having said that, timeline view can be customised if you require it to display the workflow comments.

Comment: Thanks, i.net! What does the "comment" section in the above image display then?